# How to show a collectionView at a Specific Index in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am using a library called VegaScrollFlowLayout that is located on github. I am trying to give an exact index in my collectionView, and present the data starting from that index, but I keep getting a reset back to Index 0 and not Index 10.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    collectionView.scrollToItem(
        at: NSIndexPath(item: 10, section: 0) as IndexPath,
        at: [],
            animated: false)
  
    
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably put your call to `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` in `viewDidAppear()`, not `viewWillAppear()`. In `viewWillAppear()` the collection view has not shown any cells yet. I don't think you'd need a delay that way.

Using delays is a fragile way of doing things. Better to move the code to the correct lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some digging around, I had to add a delay in the code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)
    {
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(
        at: NSIndexPath(item: 15, section: 0) as IndexPath,
        at: [],
            animated: false)

    }
 }
```

This fixed the issue.

Comment: You should probably put your call to `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` in `viewDidAppear()`, not `viewWillAppear()`. In viewWillAppear()` the collection view has not shown any cells yet. I don't think you'd need a delay that way. (Although I haven't tested it.)